Find position of a number greater than x in an array looking from down to up - Excel 365
I have an array with numbers from 1 to 500. I want to look for position of a number (say greater than 49) in that array looking from bottom to up. The first occurance of that criteria is the answer.
I don't seem to find an answer in google as nobody have searched or asked for it.

You need XMATCH() like =XMATCH(60,A:A,1,-1) with search mode -1 means search last to first.

Thanks but It has 2 issues. 1st is that 60 is absolute, how can I make it >60. 2nd issue is that it still returns the position from top to bottom even though we use -1 to search from last to first.

Can you please post few sample data and then show your desired output. Third parameter 1 of xmatch() indicate exact match or next larger item.

30
193
381
197
56
497
779
293
172
155
=XMATCH(50,A:A,1,-1) gives 5. while I need 1 because the first occurrence from last to first is 155 and it is greater than 50.

I think I have found the solution. =COUNT(AG152:AG161)+1-XMATCH(TRUE,INDEX(AG152:AG161>50,0),0,-1). Using match and index in this way returns the position searching from last to first but giving position from first to last. To convert the position I count the list number and minus the result + 1, gives me the desired result.

Thankfully, the idea sprung from xmatch as shown in your post.

Understood! You can then try this one also =XMATCH(TRUE,SORTBY(A1:A10,ROW(A1:A10),-1)>50).

Is the position the end goal, or do you need the value (or values next to it?) in that case =XLOOKUP(TRUE,G152:G16>50,G152:G161,,,-1)

the position is the end goal

Try =LET(data,A2:A11,gt_value,49,if_not_found,0,IFNA(ROWS(data)+1-XMATCH(TRUE,data>gt_value,,-1),if_not_found)).

Data is in A1:A29
Variable is in E1 (to be used as a greater than)
Return value is the position (row number in this case, but will be the position/index into the array if data does not start at row 1) of the bottommost match
using XMATCH
=XMATCH(TRUE,A1:A29>E1,0,-1)

for older versions of Excel, this can also be done using LOOKUP, but you will need to adjust the result by the starting row of the array.
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A29>E1),ROW(A1:A29))

values in A1:A29 that are greater than value in E1 are highlighted

